# Restarting an activity in a single tab in a TabActivity?

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I have a TabActivity. Each tab point to a sub activity. This works great.

Is there any clever way to refresh one of the activity tabs? I just want to 'restart' the activity in tab #3 for example. Not sure of a good way to do this other than building in refresh support to the activity itself, or clearing ALL the tabs and recreating all of them.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

Slightly more dynamic solution:

```
LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
String currentTag = tabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
Class<? extends Activity> currentClass = manager.getCurrentActivity().getClass();
manager.destroyActivity(currentTag, true);
manager.startActivity(currentTag, new Intent(this, currentClass));
```

Comment: LocalActivityManager is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Euthyphro.  This was written a year and a half ago.  Did someone already provide a better answer?  If so, which one?

Answer (score 4):

I've not tried this myself, but typically you access each individual tab's `Activity` using the [`LocalActivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html).  This can be retrieved in a `TabActivity` by using [`getLocalActivityManager()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html#getLocalActivityManager()).

It looks like you should be able to use `destroyActivity()` and `startActivity()` to restart an Activity, though I'm not exactly sure if this will work (as I've not done it myself).  One important thing to note is that the `id` of the Activity will be equivalent to the tag you set for the tab (e.g., the String you provided to `TabHost.newTabSpec(String)`).

```
LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
manager.destroyActivity("tab3", true);
manager.startActivity("tab3", new Intent(this, ThirdTab.class));
```

Comment: This generates a `NullPointerException` for me at `android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab()` line 328.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        Log.d(LOG_KEY, tabId);
        LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
        manager.destroyActivity("ID_1", true);
        manager.startActivity("ID_1", new Intent(this, YourMyActivity.class));
    }
```