# Android TabActivity pass parcelable across tabs

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, android-tabactivity

I'm trying to pass data from tab n to tab n+1 activities, based on TabActivity in the MainContainerActivity, using parcelables but can't succeed as I can not apply "getExtras" method on the tab n+1 intent.

I can pass my parcelable object from one tab to the next one if I start the tab n+1 activity using `startActivity(nextactivity)` instead of using the tab switcher with `tab.setCurrentTab(tab_n+1)`.

How shall I manage the activity intents sothat I can succeed to pass those parcelable objects, still implementing TabActivity in the MainContainer class and Activity in the tabs ?

or is there a way to force the activity start in the manifest when using `tab.setCurrentTab(tab_n+1)` ?

I read dozen of threads and have been trying many misc tests but w/o success so pls detail the answer as for a real noob :-)

EDIT:
Looking to get this working from API8 onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained here :

[Restarting an activity in a single tab in a TabActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429609/restarting-an-activity-in-a-single-tab-in-a-tabactivity)

What you want is to destroy the activity and start it again, by passing the new Parcelable "arguments" in the intent.
The suggested method will probably work, however I strongly suggest you to consider using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) instead. If you want to support version prior Android 3, you will need the [support package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). 
The examples listed in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example should get you started on Fragments.

Comment: Thx for the reply as I'm really strugglying with that. I'll look further to your hints.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simple answer to my simple 3 tabs application is using a **global object** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/461212), which also allow keeping my existing source code.